# Android AVD Manager takes so long to load

Tags: android, emulator

I've just downloaded Android AVD Manager, I started the AVD device and it takes so long to load.

This is all I got

[image]

Is this normal?

Comment: Yes, that is the Android emulator and yes it is slow, especially on a slow processor.

Answer (score 3):

That is normal. Even up to 20 mins+ is still normal on some systems. The best thing to do while developing, though, is NEVER SHUT DOWN THE AVD!

Once you get it running, it will ask you to swipe-to-unlock the screen to start, then after that, just leave it in the background while you code. When you try to run the program again, it will take mere seconds to load if the AVD is still up.

Answer (score 0):

Well... how long time does it take?

Was this the first time you launched it?

What's your target platform?

As a reference, it took me about 3 minutes to load an Android 2.2 AVD that I just created, only just 10 MB in size. That's on a Intel Core 2 Duo 2.2 GHz, 4 GB of RAM and Vista 64-bit host system.

I have pressed the power button to power it off and it has been shutting down for 15 minutes right now and has not been shut down yet. So yeah, I would say that these long delays are normal. It's interesting though that it is still responding and it is using one of the CPU cores more than the other, according to Windows Task Manager.

Comment: This is first time..Well still about 40 minutes, not yet...Target platform is 4.0.3

Comment: @HarisMuharemović It's been 40 minutes and it has NOT launched yet? What's your CPU, RAM and OS?

Comment: Ironically it's been 40 minutes now and my AVD has not shut down yet. I will assume that it will not shut down and force it to shut down by closing the window.

Comment: On the second launch it took me 1 minute to load my AVD. But it took 8 minutes to shut it down and it didn't even shut down I had to force close the window.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it takes a while to load and the performance is not the best, specially on a slower system.

Remember that it's emulating an ARM CPU and this is quite a heavy task to do.